# IQueryable List<DTO> conversion

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I need to fill an IQueryable of UserDTO with a List of TeamsDTO without a foreach-loop or materializing the data.

I have the following classes:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Team> Teams {get;set;}
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Teamname {get;set;}
    public string Description {get;set;}
}
```

And the following DTOs:

```
public class UserDTO
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public List<TeamDTO> TeamsDTOList{get;set;}
}

public class TeamDTO
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Teamname {get;set;}
}
```

And the Code so far:

```
public static IQueryable<UserDTO> GetQueryableUserDTO(IQueryable<User> query)
        {
            var retQueryable = Enumerable.Empty<UserDTO>().AsQueryable();
            try
            {
                retQueryable = query.AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(k => new UserDTO
                                {
                                    Id = k.Id,
                                    TeamsDTOList= new List<TeamDTO>()
                                    {
                                        //Can't figure out this part
                                    }
                                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                BaseManager.Write2Log(ex);
            }
            return retQueryable;
        }
```

Thanks for the help in advance.

P.S.: Classes/code are of course a simplified example.

Comment: If you have a lot of data models that you need to convert to DTOs you may want to consider a mapping tool like Automapper: https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html

Comment: Is there any reason to use the AsEnumerable? And is the try catch really needed here?

Comment: Use AutoMapper.

Comment: The try-catch is needed (Code guidelines) and the ienumerable is 'standard' as well. We don't use automapper (sadly). It's been brought up before but will not be implemented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this :

```cs
retQueryable = query.AsEnumerable().Select(k => new UserDTO()
                {
                    Id = k.Id,
                    TeamsDTOList = k.Teams.Select(t => new TeamDTO(){ Id = t.Id, Teamname = t.Teamname}).ToList()
                });
```

Comment: You just have to add .ToList() at the end because TeamsDTOList is a list type and select will return Enumerable